# Can we truncate data in a Excel sheet using Execute Sql task?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb, execute-sql-task

I have a SSIS package in which Data is loaded from Sql server to Excel sheet.
Now, whenever I run the package data got loaded with the previous loaded data. Requirement is to load only the fresh data and remove the existing data from excel sheet.
Can we use Execute sql task to Truncate data in the excel sheet also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS: Truncate Excel Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452541/ssis-truncate-excel-destination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Execute SQL TASK can be used to drop and then recreate the excel sheet so that only new data will be left following the import.  To do this add an Execute SQL Task to the Control Flow and choose EXCEL for the `ConnectionType` property.  For the SQL Statement, enter a `DROP` command with the table name followed by a `CREATE` command containing the DDL of the table (excel sheet).  An example of this is below.  Note that the `GO` keyword is necessary to run both the `CREATE` and `DROP` statements in the same task, otherwise a separate Execute SQL Task will be needed for each one.

**Example Excel DROP and CREATE Commands:**

```
DROP TABLE SheetName

GO

CREATE TABLE SheetName (
    `ID` Long,
    `NAME` LongText,
    `ImportDate` DateTime
)
```